# Tell browser close apart from navigating away in onunload

Tags: javascript

As an fontend exit routine, our web app persists some states to the server when the browser closes. However, we don't want to call the exit routine when navigating away from the app, since later the app might be navigated back to. From the exit routine's perspective, browser close and navigating away are two distinct scenarios.

One way to write the data to the server on the frontend is call the exit routine inside onunload event handler. However, we are having problems differentiating browser close and navigating away. The onunload handler is called in both cases. We need some way to tell if we are navigating away in onunload so that we don't call the exit routine.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Super helpful: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript

Comment: Why not just auto-save every X seconds when they are modifying values to be sure.  Relying on capturing the `onbeforeunload` event (and then in IE determining if it was really an unload event, not an in-page navigation) is fragile at best.

Comment: Could also take a look at the [DOM Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: scunliffe, we already have a mechanism similar to what you mentioned implemented. We just don't want to leave any "gap" possibly caused by that mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

> From the exit routine's perspective, browser close and navigating away are two distinct scenarios.

Looks like you might be able to solve this by keeping track of user state in a session cookie -- a cookie without an `expires`, or `max-age` attributes.

This way, the session state will persist when the user navigates away from the app/page, but will reset when the browser is closed.